# dumping django historical data in different database using django routers

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

I am using the django-simple-history package to track changes in my model. Now, I want to dump only the historical data into another database. I attempted to achieve this using a router, but I encountered an error:

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1824, "Failed to open the referenced table 'common_user'")`

The issue appears to be because the `common_user` table is in the default database and not in the history database.

Here's the codes:

```
# routers.py
class HistoryRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        model_name = model.__name__
        if 'historical' in model_name.lower():
            return 'history_db'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        print('3'*100)
        model_name = model.__name__
        if 'historical' in model_name.lower():
            return 'history_db'
        return 'default'

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if hints.get("db") is not None:
            return db == hints.get("db")
        if model_name != None:
            if 'historical' in model_name.lower():
                return db == 'history_db'
        return db == 'default'
```

```
#models.py
class Profile(models.Model):

    profile_type = models.ForeignKey(ProfileType, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    nickname = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    org = models.ForeignKey(
        Org, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name="user_org"
    )
    address = models.ManyToManyField(Address, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_section_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_organization_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_organization_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_of_joining = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    referral = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    referred = models.CharField(
        max_length=64, blank=False, null=False, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4().hex)
    history = HistoricalRecords(m2m_fields=(address, ), use_base_model_db=False,  cascade_delete_history=True)
```

```
#settings.py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['src.common.routers.HistoryRouter']
```

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: The issue is probably because simply history by default tracks the user that makes the change (or aims to do that), and since that person is in a different table, the problems start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because [django-simple-history](/questions/tagged/django-simple-history) keeps track of the user that makes the modification, or at least tries to do so. But since the model of that user is in a different database, the `FOREIGN KEY` can not be added.

But that scenario is taken into account: you can specify the field for the user, and thus change it to a (nullable) `IntegerField` for example:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # …
    history = HistoricalRecords(
        m2m_fields=(address,),
        use_base_model_db=False,
        cascade_delete_history=True,
        history_user_id_field=models.IntegerField(null=True),
    )
```

---

> **Note**: Please *don't* use `default=uuid.uuid4().hex`. This will generate a UUID the first time it interprets the model when you start the server, and use that UUID as default for *all* items it will construct. Additionally, it will also include that field in a new migration each time you migrate, since the default is always different. Use `default=uuid.uuid4` instead.

Comment: I just had to define allow_relation method in router.